# Admin Ajax causing slow wordpress site (waterfall)

Tags: php, wordpress, waterfall, admin-ajax

[image: Text]

Can someone help me figure out how to fix the slow admin-ajax.php problem? Sorry I'm new to wordpress.

I understand it could be related to the wpbakery (visual composer) plugin used to build the site. But I've disabled plugins one by one and can't figure out the cause.

EDIT: I've used Heartbeat API Plugin as well to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNfRD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just deferring it with W3 Total Cache under the Minify settings for JS by copying and pasting the admin-ajax.php script.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins might be using this admin-ajax for the various purposes which eventually slows down the website.

The best solution is by disabling the Heartbeat API. Install the [Heartbeat control plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/). Heartbeat control plugin allows you to easily manage the frequency of the WordPress heartbeat API. Through this plugin, the heartbeat API can be disabled entirely.

Refer to the below articles for more info.

https://visualmodo.com/reduce-admin-ajax-server-load-wordpress/

https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-fix-admin-ajax-file

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/reduce-admin-ajax-php-related-server-load-wordpress/

https://kinsta.com/blog/admin-ajax/

Comment: Hi @Rajeev, I've installed the Heartbeat plugin, and while it has removed some, there is still one admin-ajax call that doesn't go away.

Comment: You need to find out which plugin is triggering that ajax call and you cannot simply remove everything as it's important for certain operations. Make sure you're quite sure about what you're doing. Do accept and upvote my answer if it helps.

Comment: Well, I've deactivated each plugin one by one, reran gtmetrix, and it's still there every time. Could be an issue with the theme, but somehow another site that uses this theme was able to bypass this issue.

Comment: This might be because of the feature which you have on this website but not on another website. Try switching the theme to ThentySixteen or TwentySeventeen to see if the problem is with the theme.

Comment: yes, it might have something to do with the theme as it doesn't appear on my other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, are you using wp advanced search plugin? This looks like its not supported and causing this issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. No, it's not one of my plugins unless wpbakery uses it etc.